# Не записываются данные в SharedPreference Android

Tags: android-shared-preferences

```
/** обработчик нажатия на кнопку. Есть некий Dialog с реализацией 
    MultiChoiceItems, хотелось бы выбранные значения сохранить в 
    SharedPreferences. Но почему-то никакие значения не сохраняются. 
*/
OnClickListener myBtnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Получаем выбранные значения, работает
        SparseBooleanArray sbArray = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

        String[] chckedCostsStringArray = new String[sbArray.size()];
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        for (int i = 0; i < sbArray.size(); i++) {
            int key = sbArray.keyAt(i);
            if (sbArray.get(key))
                Log.d("qwe", "checked: " + key);

            chckedCostsStringArray[i] = String.valueOf(key);
            Toast.makeText(mActivity,"checked: " + chckedCostsStringArray[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Занесение данных в SharedPreferences
            editor.putString("values" + i, String.valueOf(key));

        }
        editor.commit();
    }
};
```

Comment: Работает ли SharedPreferences в диалогах?

Comment: Где вы проверяете то, что вы записали?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `editor.apply();`

`commit()` записывает данные синхронно (блокируя вызываемый поток из). Затем он информирует вас об успешности операции.

`apply()` расписывает данные, которые должны быть записаны асинхронно. Он не информирует вас об успехах операции.